# How to read azure service queue message in Logic apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create small Azure Logic app which will have some order flows.I will get the message in service bus queue. I need to get the message in logic app and based upon the message content, I need to follow the further steps. The message will contain the order data as well. There will be conditional logic, let's suppose, if order type is "new", I need to call HTTP request where I need to pass the message data as body content in POST request.

I have create a service bus queue and in logic apps, added service bus trigger which will be called when message will be received in service bus queue(automatically).

I need to able to implement conditional logic but as i am newbie in this, i am not sure how to pass this data in condtional logic from message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to mention the condition in the block and design the flow that we require. If the condition is true I have added the HTTP action mentioning the required details. For understanding purpose I have mentioned the other condition to trigger an email.

Here the flow of my logic app
[image]

If you want to continue the flow just click Add an action in True Connector.

REFERENCES:
[Get started with Azure Service Bus queues (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus) - Azure Service Bus | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues)

Comment: Thank you for the info. This will be message content.

{
  "EventType": "NewOrder",
  "EventSource": {
    "source": "a",
    "akey": "sss"
  },
  "CreatedAt": "2021-09-27T10:54:11.2629327+00:00",
  "data": {
    "ItemId": 817,
    "OrderId": 278
  }
} I need to add condition on "EventType" and then call api where i need to pass the data itemId, orderId, source etc

Comment: { "EventType": "NewOrder", "EventSource": {"source": "a", "akey": "sss" }, "CreatedAt": "2021-09-27T10:54:11.2629327+00:00", "data": { "ItemId": 817,"OrderId": 278 }} I need to add condition on "EventType" and then call api where i need to pass the data itemId, orderId, source etc. If i run the above condition , the HTTP fails with this message "ActionBranchingConditionNotSatisfied. The execution of template action 'HTTP' skipped: the branching condition for this action is not satisfied." if i run HTTP without condition, it gets executed successfully.

Comment: @vivek If that's the case then you need to include condition in Condition Connector as `EventType`  is Equal to `NewOrder` Hope in the URL you are including the URL to which you are posting

Comment: Yes, got it working. Thank you. @SwethaKandikonda-MT